# Xとした usage and grammar?

Tags: grammar, usage

I've looked over my books but I can't find the answer. All I know is that とする can be used to express something you assume. Such as 温度は一定とする。 We assume the temperate is constant. Also I read we can use it for feelings such as ほっとする and look. So where can I read about this other usage? I have an example meaning too.

Can anyone please be so kind and explain how this grammar works as used down below.

> 周囲は暗く**鬱蒼{うっそう}とした**林に覆われていて、周りには街灯も少ないから夜なんて真っ暗だ。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me break your **鬱蒼とした** into the parts of the speech.

**鬱蒼とした** is separated into **鬱蒼**　( to Japanese language learners this is frequently called as **na-adjective**, but I would like to call it as **[quasi-adjective ( adjective noun )](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quasi-adjective)**, and here, it is used as the stem of the quasi-adjective = **A noun that functions as an adjective.** ( Kindly be reminded there are many disputes regarding how to deal with this as the na-adjective or if it is the noun+auxiliary etc.　( For example, **[Motoki Tokieda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motoki_Tokieda)** is taking the latter stance. Here I would like to the latter stance. ) **meaning, profuse, dense, thick etc**, )   ***/***  **と**, case-marking particle, followed by the **[substantive, ( please see grammar )](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/substantive)**, meaning **like, as if, etc** ( Please refer to the further information below ) ***/*** **し** ( 連用形（れんようけい）,the continuative form ( **meaning, to be continued to such as verbs, auxiliaries etc..** ) of the verb **する**, meaning, **do or be ( this case )** ***/***　**た**, 連体形,the attributive form ( meaning, **after this follows a noun**, so in your sentence the noun **林**, forest ) of the auxiliary た, which denotes here the continuation. )

So if you take not 鬱蒼とした, but 鬱蒼とした林, after the long and complicated Japanese grammar above, it would stand as a subjective, meaning **"dense, thick, dark, etc., forest".**

Now let's take a look at the **[case marking particle](http://www2.dokkyo.ac.jp/%7Eesemi008/kenkyu/kumagai.html)**

From the source, 4,

> 山と積まれた乾草

meaning, 乾草, a noun, **meaning dried grasses or hay**,

The translation will be

> the accumulated hay **like** a mountain.

Comment: "why the word -- native speakers is allowed?" >> ここは、「言語」を論じている場所で、「国籍」を論じている場所ではないからです。でもとにかく foreigners はネガティブなニュアンスがあるのでやめた方がいいと思いますよ。。

Comment: Ugh thank you. I understand. You know English more than me. I apologize that I almost didn't know the word **foreigners** would give negative impressions.

Comment: One reason to avoid the term "na-adjective" in this case is that な isn't used―と is.

Comment: Certainly. As snaiboat san says, if we take 鬱蒼 as some kind of adjective, it is categorized as タルト型． ( Taruto type )

Comment: I think I've been directed to this post about 18 times now. Finally, on a blustery horrible winter morning in the UK, something finally fell into place in my brain and I can now understand the meaning of adj+とした+noun, although I'm slightly embarrassed that it's taken so long to get there... :D