# What's the point of adding とした here in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, adjectives, reading-comprehension

Here is the sentence of my question.

希望に満ち溢れていたはずの"あなた"がなぜあんなに荒凉とした場所にうずくまっていたの。

I can understand what it's trying to say to some degree yet it confuses me why とした is used in the sentence.

With the wonder I checked とした up in the dictionary and got no explanatory answer. And I wonder if it's an adjective or a particle added to modify nouns and turn them into adjectives.

Comment: @Spoonail, does the page you've linked to really answer this question sufficiently? My own impression is that the  タリ活用の形容動詞＋と＋した pattern is different enough from 副詞 +と+した that it probably merits a separate explanation, if there isn't already one elsewhere on the site. (I'd like to read such an explanation myself, which is one reason I've upvoted Kismet's question.)

Comment: @Nanigashi This 荒涼と is 副詞(noun + と). Well, you can see it as 連用形 form of タリ活用の形容動詞, but in the first place the line between them is blurry because タリ活用の形容動詞 is originally made from 副詞(noun + と) + ある like 荒涼と+ある -> 荒涼とぁる -> 荒涼たる.

Comment: @Spoonail that's exactly how I do see it, except I'd say that what's "original" in the case of タリ活用の形容動詞 is not the adverb (e.g., 荒凉と), but the underlying noun (荒凉). That's one reason I think this might deserve a separate answer, or at least an expansion of that answer by naruto; with examples like がっかりとした and ゆっくりとした, there is no underlying noun, is there? There are also practical ramifications that Kismet and other learners should perhaps be alerted to, such as the fact that the と is not optional with these タリ活用の形容動詞, and the existence of the literary form with たる instead of とした.

Comment: @Nanigashi `> the と is not optional with these タリ活用の形容動詞` Ah, that makes sense! I missed that. Then, as you said, タリ活用の形容動詞+と + した might require other answer than the one of 副詞 (such as ゆっくり) + と + した. But still I've found [the one of タリ活用の形容動詞+と + した](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27389/x%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f-usage-and-grammar) and this Kismet's question is duplicate. If it's not enough explanation to you, I think you should post your own question focusing on the difference between タリ活用の形容動詞＋と＋した and 副詞 +と+した or other your concern.

Comment: I should have link that question ("Xとした usage and grammar?") as duplicate. I'll try to add it to the header (though probably only moderators can do that... ).

Comment: @Spoonail, thanks –  that link to "Xとした usage and grammar?" is definitely a step in the right direction. I think another question on this topic probably isn't necessary, and a new question would most likely just be closed as a duplicate anyway. However, I do think Kentaro's answer could be improved upon. (For one thing, he conflates ナリ and タリ活用の形容詞 in a way that's unhelpful.) I'm not even sure if it's possible since that answer has been accepted, but I hope someone will clean it up or write a new one. I'd try to do it myself if I thought I were qualified, but I know I'm not!